# Post request in an AngularJs single page application

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am building a single page application in Spring MVC and AngularJS. I have a header-footer-sidebar and an ng-view section where all the pages are loaded by Ajax with a routeProvider.
The thing is that the routeProvider **is only working with GET requests** which means I cannot pass any parameters. (**I don't want to pass all the form data in the url**)
I want to submit a form using **Ajax POST request** and in the same time change the ng-view content. Is this possible using Angular routeProvider?

The solution I have thought so far is to post the form data, receive a success message and then change the hash of the url in order to trigger a new request to the server for the new page. This solution though, has the drawback of performing 2 requests to the server while I want to perform only one.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to realize that routeProviders are there to change routes insider your application, not to pass data to server. use a service or a factory to pass data to the server, and return your response page from there.
here is a simple example,

form:-

```
<form name="empForm" ng-controller="insertEmpCtrl" ng-submit="insertEmp()">
name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" ng-model="formData.lname"/>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

routing:-

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl : '/your/project/root.html',
        controller : 'controler1'
    })
    .when('/page',{
        templateUrl : '/your/project/page.html',
        controller : 'controler2'
    });
});
```

factory:-

```
myApp.factory('factoryname', function(){
return{
    insertData: function($scope,$http){
        var json_data = JSON.stringify($scope.formData);


        $http.post(url, json_data, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        }).success(function(){
            console.log("done");
        }).error(function(){
            console.log("error");
        });
    }
}
});
```

controller:-

```
myApp.controller('controller1',['$scope','$http','$rootScope','factoryname',function($scope,$http,$rootScope,factoryname){

$scope.insertEmp = function(){

    $scope.formFactory = factoryname.insertData($scope,$http);

};
}]);
```

spring controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/aurlPattern",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String insertmethod(@RequestBody  FormModelObject FormModelObject) {

    //do something


    return "responsePage";
}
```