# Angular - routeProvider with Post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a simple page using angular where I do video upload, but when using the ng-view, I can no longer use the method POST I  created.
What should I do in routeProvider for the POST to normal operation?

Below is my routeProvider and Controller code

app.js:

```
angular.module('videoUpload', ['ngFileUpload', 'ngRoute']);

angular.module("videoUpload").config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/videolist", {
        templateUrl: "/views/videolist.html",
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/videoinsert", {
        templateUrl: "/views/videoinsert.html",
        resolve: {

        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("videoUpload").
controller('videoUploadController', ['$http', 'Upload', '$scope', function($http, Upload, $scope){

  $http.get('/public/videos').then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.videos = response.data;
  });

  $scope.submit = function(){
    Upload.upload({
      url: '/public/videos',
      method: 'post',
      data: $scope.upload
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      $scope.videos.push(response.data);
      $scope.upload = {};
    })
  }
}]);
```

My POST:

```
router.post('/videoinsert', video.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);
  var newUpload = {
    title: req.body.title,
    author: req.body.author,
    description: req.body.description,
    created_at: Date.now(),
    file: req.file
  };
  Upload.create(newUpload, function (err, next) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      res.send(newUpload);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423284/post-request-in-an-angularjs-single-page-application

Comment: I'm still learning, I can not quite understand how to do this in my code.

Comment: In your POST route, you have `Upload.create` , is that `Upload` your collection name? And try giving more `console.log()` between statements to find out where exactly your code fails

Comment: I used factory, now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing `Controller` in your `routeProvider`.

Try this:

```
angular.module("videoUpload").config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/videolist", {
        templateUrl: "/views/videolist.html",
        //use controller here also,if required

    });
    $routeProvider.when("/videoinsert", {
        templateUrl: "/views/videoinsert.html",
        // assuming 'videoUploadController' is the controller used in this case
        controller : 'videoUploadController',
        resolve: {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The error persists: POST http://localhost:3000/public/videos 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: error code 500 means, there is some issue in your post Route. Check in the backend route, what is the actual problem. You can use `console.log()` to debug while checking for where your code fails.

Comment: I inserted my post at the beginning of the topic, could help telling me what's wrong?

Comment: In your POST route `Upload.create` ,`Upload` is a collection, right? 
Try to debug the code by adding more `console.log()` in your code. Add multiple console and try to find exactly where you are facing the issues

Comment: According to my previous experiences, ngFileupload might create this problem, so you may try POST call after removing the middleware  `video.single('file')` and see if the error still exists.